# Nicer syntax for looping through array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I have A, an array of arrays of length 3. For example A = [[a1, b1, c3], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], [a4, b4, c4]]. Right now I am looping over it like this:

```
A.each do |elem|
  puts(elem[0].foo)
  puts(elem[1].bar)
  puts(elem[2].baz)
end
```

Since I am using a lot of different properties in the loop, the code gets pretty messy and unreadable. Plus, the local name elem[0] isn't very descriptive. Is there a way to use something like this?

```
A.each do |[a,b,c]|
  puts(a.foo)
  puts(b.bar)
  puts(c.baz)
end
```

I'm pretty new to ruby I don't really know where to look for something like this.

Comment: Try `do |a,b,c|` instead of `do |[a,b,c]|`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Out of curiosity, what is this kind of thing called?

Comment: Multiple assignment, several languages have this feature including ruby

Comment: The Ruby docs refer to it as [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). Note that the size of the array must be known to contain three elements to express the block variables as `|a,b,c|`.

Comment: What @CarySwoveland said; however if the array contains more than 3 elements but `a` and `b` are the imperative, one can use array decomposition with the splat (`*`) operator as well such that `|a,b,*c|` (it is customary to use `*rest` in place of  `*c`). In this case `a` and `b` will be the first and second elements of the `Array` and `*c` will contain 0 or more elements that identify the rest of the `Array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its known as de-structuring (or decomposition in the [Ruby docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition)):

```
A.each do |(a,b,c)|
  puts(a.foo)
  puts(b.bar)
  puts(c.baz)
end
```

You can also use a splat (*) if the number of elements is unknown which will gather the remaining elements:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]].each do |(first, *rest)|
  puts "first: #{first}"
  puts "rest: #{rest}"
end


[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]].each do |(first, *middle, last)|
  puts "first: #{first}"
  puts "middle: #{middle}"
  puts "last: #{last}"
end
```

Comment: Note that the parentheses are optional if the block is yielded with one parameter that is an array. Meaning that `A.each do |a,b,c|` would also work here.

Comment: @3limin4t0r true. I still do like them as they give a heads up that there is de-structuring going on.